# add pdf crop marks using ghostscript

Tags: printing, ghostscript

I currently have a ghostscript that downsample all the images in the input pdf file. I also want the output file to have crop marks or maybe draw a box around the edge of the document to serve as cutting guide. How do I do that? Here is my current code.

```bash
gs \
    -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
    -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 \
    -dDownsampleColorImages=true \
    -dDownsampleGrayImages=true \
    -dDownsampleMonoImages=true \
    -dColorImageResolution=72 \
    -dGrayImageResolution=72 \
    -dMonoImageResolution=72 \
    -dNOPAUSE \
    -dQUIET \
    -dBATCH \
    -sOutputFile=testdownsample.pdf \
    test.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

You add the code to draw the crop marks/box separately you will need to create a /EndPage procedure to do this.

Comment: @ KenS I'm a newbie on ghost scripts could you revise my code and show me how to do this?

Comment: You need to learn PostScript to do this, which is a programming language (Ghostscript is a PostScript interpreter, basically). You need to write PostScript which draws the marks you want at the locations you want them on the page. No changes to the Ghostscript command line are going to help you here, so revising it won't help you. I couldn't even begin to write the PostScript code without knowing exactly what you want (and I'm afraid that isn't an offer to do it for you....)